# getting error while making the electron.js build with nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

when i am trying for electron.js build with nextJs getting this error again and again while i've updated my packages and re-installed node modules also but unable to solve this

```
C:\Users\Himanshu\Desktop\claros\node_modules\minizlib\index.js:192
  [_superWrite] (data) {
   ^
TypeError: Class extends value #<Object> is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Himanshu\Desktop\claros\node_modules\minizlib\index.js:192:4)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Himanshu\Desktop\claros\node_modules\app-builder-lib\node_modules\tar\lib\pack.js:26:14)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Himanshu\Desktop\claros\node_modules\app-builder-lib\node_modules\tar\lib\create.js:6:14)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I've tried to update and change the dependencies version also uninstall and then install node_modules and also changes the node version